# Primefaces datafilter issue

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to apply filter on my datatable but i don't why it is not working.I have checked all the things again and again but still it is not working and even not showing any error or exception.Here is my code
page.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="masterResult" value="#{masterSearch.masterSearchResultList}" var="srvc" 
                             styleClass="display" style="cursor:pointer;" rows="6" 
                             paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             widgetVar="viewTable" filteredValue="#{masterSearch.filterMasterSearchResult}">
                                
                                <p:column filterBy="#{srvc.serviceNumber}"  
                                                headerText="Service Number"
                                                filterMatchMode="endsWith">  
                                        <h:outputText value="#{srvc.serviceNumber}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                
                                <p:column headerText="Rank">
                                #{srvc.rank}
                                </p:column>
                                
                                <p:column headerText="Name">
                                #{srvc.name}
                                </p:column>
                                         
                                <p:column headerText="Course">
                                #{srvc.course}
                                </p:column>
                                         
                                <p:column headerText="Unit">
                                #{srvc.unit}
                                </p:column>
                                         
                                <p:column headerText="Relation">
                                #{srvc.relation}
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
```

Here I am getting the values properly but when I write anthing in filter text field (showed by primefaces)it won't work.
Please help if anyone get idea about this
Thanks

## Edit:

```
public class MasterSearch {
    
    String serviceNumber;
    String rank;
    String fullName;
    String CNICNumber;
    String phoneNumber;
    String emailAddress;
    List<MasterSearchResult> masterSearchResultList;
    List<MasterSearchResult> filterMasterSearchResult;

               // getter 
               //  setters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this part : `filteredValue="#{masterSearch.filterMasterSearchResult}"`

check my sample from here : https://dl.dropbox.com/s/v3ihl25aozt8qyn/mavenproject.zip?dl=1

Comment: yes it is srvc.serviceNumber.I pasted old code mistakenly but now i edited in my question.I have pasted my bean please chk

Comment: Please check with `filterMatchMode="contains"`.

Comment: yes I checked it with "contains" , "startsWith" , "exact" but it is not working

Comment: which version of primefaces do you use? could you please upload the code somewhere then I will check the code!

Comment: code is actually so large so i didn't paste it here.Which part do you want to see in code? i will paste that part.I am using the latest version of primefaces which is primefaces-3.4.RC1.jar

Comment: Found the problem, updated the answer. check it and give me the feedback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16071/discussion-between-ssk-and-heidarzadeh)

Comment: please enable your firebug console and check if you have any client side error. I just uploaded my sample maven project. simply build it and test it. check filtering on user name column, it works.  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/v3ihl25aozt8qyn/mavenproject.zip?dl=1

Comment: OK by the way i created another project where this is working fine but i don't know why it is not working in this project.as well my selectionmode is also not working her.Anyway thx and your effort is highly appreciable ...

Comment: feel free to create other questions for your problems and describe them well and paste your code ;)